# Setting URL with logged in user id from the front end blade in LARAVEL 6

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, href, laravel-6

Hello I'm trying to set an URL (href) from my blade(welcome.blade.php) to logged in user's user profile.

My url has to be like this -> sample.com/profile/24

there, 24 is logged in user's user id

```
<a href="{{URL('/profile/{{ Auth::user()->id }}')}}" class="btn btn-primary">profile</a>
```

but when I run the code it gives me following exception,

**Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `{{}}` again inside `{{}}`

**Change**

```
<a href="{{URL('/profile/{{ Auth::user()->id }}')}}" class="btn btn-primary">profile</a>
```

**to**

```
<a href="{{URL('/profile/'.Auth::user()->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">profile</a>
```

Comment: nope tried still getting this error, Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
syntax error, unexpected 'change' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: try this `<a href="{{URL('/profile/'.Auth::user()->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">profile</a>`

Comment: Hey that worked! I would up vote but not enough credits.

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept this answer if you do not upvote

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have a route setup to show a users profile you can also do

```php
<a href="{{route('users.show', Auth::user()->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">profile</a>
```

Then your route would be something like this

```php
Route::get('profile/{user}', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
```